# Using cordova with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova

Im trying to code an android app with cordova. But I want to use node.js for it. Is this possible?
I tried to use nodejs-mobile-cordova plugin, but its too old to use.

Trying to use mongoose for app.

ok...

Im changing my question to: which **cloud** database should I use for cordova

Comment: if nodejs-mobile-cordova is too old, what do you want to accomplish? Which benifit you are looking for using NodeJS as you can write all your cordova stuff in JS?

Comment: `I want to use node.js` is not a valid reason to use nodejs-mobile-cordove as both node.js and cordova are ways that allow you to use javascript to accomplish a task. In the case of node.js it allows you to use javascript to write desktop/server apps and in the case of cordova it allows you to use javascript to write mobile apps. What node.js API do you need for your cordova app?

Comment: Im trying to use mongoose for my project.

Comment: Define "use mongoose". Are you trying to include a mongoose client in your app or are you trying to run a mongoose server on the phone?

Comment: I want to connect to a mongodb server, I can do that myself, I used mongoose in my other node.js projects. I want to connect to mongodb server with mongoose and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but Google lead me here sometime back so I'm writing here what I found.

[Node.js for Mobile](https://github.com/JaneaSystems/nodejs-mobile-cordova) is still a valid option to use. Another simpler solution is [androidjs](https://github.com/android-js), which abstracts some of the logic and simplifies the integration.

I am also working on a few projects to leverage some node libraries without having to host a node server somewhere.

To answer the question in the comment above - yes this is the use case. You sometimes don't want to host a separate server and the cost to afford it yourself, instead you offload it to the user's machine by packaging a node server with the app itself.

Another usecase is to handle AR apps / drones as mentioned in this [SO comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14513029/phonegap-with-node-js?rq=3#comment32475176_14513334).