# How to use a Node.js web server with an Apache Cordova Application

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, visual-studio, cordova

I have designed an Apache Cordova Application that uses a Node.js web server to pull data from a web API and allows the Javascript based project to use data pulled from this API.

Is there a way that I can use this Node web server across an iphone implementation of this cordova application? I am currently testing the application by pulling data from the website's API, hosting in on a node (ex. localhost:3000) and then pulling the data from that address in the JS file in my project.

How can I implement this server so that it can be used on an iOS mobile device?

Comment: You want to run nodejs on an iOS device?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Native IOS app and node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10463121/native-ios-app-and-node-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to host your Node server somewhere so that devices can see it on a network, then [Amazon AWS Elastic Beanstalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs.html) has an easy solution for that - just upload your Node project in a Zip file and they manage the server environment for you.

There's several other options out there depending on your needs, for example [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#introduction) may be a good alternative.